# How to skip certain os.walk() directories and process some of those remaining in a special way?

Tags: python, os.walk

Edited for clarity: I'm trying to get the url of a certain file type within certain folders and subfolders. I have a list of folders that I never want to enter during the walk called `bannedDir`. If any words from `bannedDir` appears, I want to skip these directories entirely from the walk, which I believe I have done. I have a list of regex expressions called `flaggedDir`. If any of the words from `flaggedDir` are in the root directory, I want to do something to everything below that root.

What I want to do below that root is first, exclude searching in directories that are in `excludedDir` which consists of all entries from bannedDir and some entries from `flaggedDir`. Then I want to get the mtime of all xls files or `fileType` from the remaining folders. Then store the maximum mtime from that list of mtimes which I've called `iniList`.

Current code below.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topDir, topdown=True):
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in bannedDir]    
   if flaggedDir.search(root) is not None:
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in excludedDir]
       for name in files:
           if name.lower().endswith(fileTypes):
               lastModif = [];
               timeIndex = [];
               fileLocation = os.path.join(root, name);
               time = os.path.getmtime(fileLocation);
               timeIndex.append(time);                             
               lastModif.append([fileLocation,time]);
       if len(lastModif) > 0:
        iniList.append(max(lastModif, key=lambda item: item[1]));
```

so for example,

```
topDir = [C:\\Test\]
fileTypes = '.xls'
bannedDir = [a,b]
flaggedDir = [c,d]
excludedDir = [a,b,c]

dir a -- file 1.xls,
dir b -- file 5.exe,
dir c -- file 2.exe,
dir d -- file 3.xls, file 4.exe, file 5.xls
```

I should be able to get only file3.xls & file 5.xls as dir a, b and c should have been skipped. Then I should just get file 3.xls as 3 has an mtime of 5000 whereas file 5 has an mtime of 2000. My question is it appears I'm traversing twice over certain directories with my code. I'm also not getting the maximum each subdirectory. How do I fix this?

Comment: maybe add the dirs you want to skip into a dictionary and skip the directory if it is in the dictionary

Comment: What is `excludedDir`?

Comment: excludedDir includes everything in bannedDir as well as some items from flaggedDir. I don't want to walk anything in excludedDir.

Comment: OK, so you have `bannedDir` and `excludedDir`, but what should trigger the inclusion of files into the group you need to check the timestamps of? In other words, what's special about file1-file6 that makes them different from other files in other subdirectories? Is it just the `if d2 not in excludedDir` conditional? I think you need to [edit] your question and clear-up some of the confusion (including mentioning that you already have working code that skips the  `bannedDir` directories). I also see that `fileTypes` isn't defined anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
if flaggedDir.search(root) is not None:
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in excludedDir]
else:
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in bannedDir]
```